# Open existing Highcharts chart on JQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm working on a Java-Spring web application that uses Highcharts. I would like to be able to click on an existing chart on page and then re-open it on a big dialog, resizing the chart to make it bigger.
My current code is a javascript that gets the data from the model to generate several charts on the same page:

```
<script>
    $().ready(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < parks.length; i++) {
                units = unitsMap[parks[i]];     //Units is an array with all units from park parks[i]
                html = "<table><tr>";
                for (var j = 0; j < units.length; j++) {
                    html = html + '<td>' +
                            '<div id="chart' + units[j] + '" class="demo-placeholder chart" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></div>' +
                            '</td>';
                }
                $("#chart" + parks[i]).html(html + "</tr></table>");
                for (var j = 0; j < units.length; j++) {
                    plot(units[j]);
                }
            }//END_FOR
    });
</script>
```

The code that generates the chart is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            //Function that plots the highcharts chart
            function plot(parkUnit, data) {
                $("#chart" + parkUnit).highcharts({
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    chart: {
                        type: 'scatter',
                        zoomType: 'xy',
                        events: {
                            click: function () {
                                alert("aaaaaa");
                            }
                        }
                    },
/////// Other plot options //////
                    series: data
                });
            }//END_FUNCTION
```

I've saved some options because they're not relevant. As you can see I've tried to play with the chart.events.click but I don't exactly know if this is the solution.
You can see as well that my javascript is generating on a for loop several charts that will be populated later by the `plot(units[j])` function, and I would like to use the existing chart on page to be opened on a big dialog window, instead of generating a new one (because I already have lots of charts on page).
Do you think is there any way of doing this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe you consider use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/aZekJ/)  solution, to combine highcharts and highslide.

Comment: It requires a license for corporate deploying... :(  Thanks anyway

Comment: So catch click event on the chart, then initialise a popup and then inisilaise new chart inside.

Comment: I wanted to avoid creating a new chart, but after trying several different options with no success I finally applied what you suggested, @SebastianBochan. However, I'm not really happy with this solution because a user can easily have 30 charts on page and I don't want to have them all duplicated...

Comment: Try to use clone function in jquery, which allows to skip chart initialisation.